# Extract graph as image

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to extract graphs from a sheet, based on the title of the graph.

For example, I have five sets of graphs on a sheet, each named by every working day of the week. I would like to extract for only the graphs which have "tuesday" in the graph title.

After researching online and finding how to extract all graphs as image I tried:

```vb
Dim objCht as ChartObject
For each objCht in Activesheet.Chartobjects
objCht.Chart.ChartTitle("Tuesday").Export "C:\folder\" & objcht.topleftcell.Value & ".jpg", "JPG"
next objCht
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim objCht As ChartObject
For Each objCht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    If objCht.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Tuesday" Then
        'Use your code to export 
Next objCht
```

It would be simpler if you simply named your chart "Tuesday".  You could just export it immediately without looping thru every other chart on the sheet.

[image]